# Rails 5 Actioncable not showing new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I trying to get action cable working. So I created a simple app with model Division with attribute name.

index.html.erb

```
  <div class="container">

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% content_for(:page_header) {"DIVISIONS"} %>

<table class="table table-striped">

  <thead >
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <div id='divisions'>
    <%= render @divisions %>
  </div>
  </tbody>

</div>
<br>

<%= link_to 'New Division', new_division_path %>
</div>
```

_division.html.erb partial

```
    <tr>
  <td><%= division.name %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', division %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_division_path(division) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', division, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

app/assets/javascripts/channels/division.coffee

```
    App.division= App.cable.subscriptions.create "DivisionChannel",
  connected: ->


  disconnected: ->


  received: (data) ->

    $("#divisions").append(data["division"])

  create: (division) ->

    @perform 'create', division: division
```

app/channels/division_channel.rb

```
class DivisionChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

    def subscribed
      stream_from "divisions_channel"
    end

    def unsubscribed
      # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
    end

    def create(data)
      # data is like parameters received from front end
      Division.create({ name: data['name'] })
    end
  end
```

divisions_controller

```
  class DivisionsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @divisions = Division.all
      end

      def new
        @division = Division.new
      end



          def create
       division = Division.new(division_params)
       if division.save
         ActionCable.server.broadcast 'divisions',
           division: division.name
         head :ok
       end
     end

      def edit
        @division = Division.find_by_id(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @division = Division.find_by_id(params[:id])

          respond_to do |format|
            if @division.update(division_params)
              format.html { redirect_to @division, notice: 'Division was successfully updated.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @division }
            else
              format.html { render :edit }
              format.json { render json: @division.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end


      def delete
      end

      def destroy
        @division.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to divisions_url, notice: 'Division was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      def show
          @division = Division.find_by_id(params[:id])
      end

      def division_params
          params.require(:division).permit(:name)
        end
    end
```

division.rb

```
class Division < ApplicationRecord
  after_create_commit do
    DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

app/jobs/division_creation_event_broadcast_job_job.rb

```
class DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(division)

    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'divisions_channel', division: render_division(division)

  end

  private

  def render_division(division)

    ApplicationController.render(partial: 'divisions/division', locals: { division: division})
  end
end
```

When I create a new division and redirected to http://localhost:3000/divisions the screen is blank, the record is saved but not broadcasted on the other browser.

This is what I get on terminal:

```
Started POST "/divisions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-18 22:08:50 +0800
Processing by DivisionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+JjDpuJXIlnJc+yZXVJbBx9JeYA1X1owW5bOH4x6hTiddEWLst6F/fup7r1Kz0L4+6CKDsp9C0NorNVxzuh9gQ==", "division"=>{"name"=>"dgfhfdg"}, "commit"=>"Create Division"}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `divisions` (`name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('dgfhfdg', '2017-11-18 14:08:50', '2017-11-18 14:08:50')
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
[ActiveJob] Enqueued DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob (Job ID: a3e4564d-6743-44da-9d48-dbb114812a67) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x007f02f80c1708 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://bcz/Division/61>>
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to divisions: {:division=>"dgfhfdg"}
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)


  Division Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `divisions`.* FROM `divisions` WHERE `divisions`.`id` = 61 LIMIT 1
[ActiveJob] [DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob] [a3e4564d-6743-44da-9d48-dbb114812a67] Performing DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob (Job ID: a3e4564d-6743-44da-9d48-dbb114812a67) from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x007f02f809a7e8 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://bcz/Division/61>>
[ActiveJob] [DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob] [a3e4564d-6743-44da-9d48-dbb114812a67]   Rendered divisions/_division.html.erb (0.9ms)
[ActiveJob] [DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob] [a3e4564d-6743-44da-9d48-dbb114812a67] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to divisions_channel: {:division=>"<tr>\n  <td>dgfhfdg</td>\n  <td><a href=\"/divisions/61\">Show</a></td>\n  <td><a href=\"/divisions/61/edit\">Edit</a></td>\n  <td><a data-confirm=\"Are you sure?\" rel=\"nofollow\" data-method=\"delete\" href=\"/divisions/61\">Destroy</a></td>\n</tr>\n"}
[ActiveJob] [DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob] [a3e4564d-6743-44da-9d48-dbb114812a67] Performed DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob (Job ID: a3e4564d-6743-44da-9d48-dbb114812a67) from Async(default) in 6.06ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you set a breakpoint in `DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob` and does it get called? If yes, does `ActionCable.server.broadcast 'divisions_channel'` trigger the code in your front end inside `app/assets/javascripts/channels/division.coffee`? You can check that by setting a breakpoint in your js code

Comment: Hi, I tried to set the breakpoints and both DivisionCreationEventBroadcastJob and app/assets/javascripts/channels/division.coffee get called. But I thought that was clear from output in terminal too. At this point I think the problem is in the view.

Comment: Sorry actually code in app/assets/javascripts/channels/division.coffee isn't getting called as the breakpoint isn't triggered.

Comment: I wrote an answer, you need to quote me to notify me @Catmal

Answer (score 0):

This is my server log when I transmit a message

```
Started POST "/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-19 20:35:09 +0100
Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"K3oc4eHMcihA38CNFSFifxHAQ7qsCqqwhxkAcf2+RoCfHL+vW6B4N1w4amHR+6Hy7TOQlOSEJ9A7KWsNNKTnnA==", "message"=>{"content"=>" asfdsfsd", "chatroom_id"=>"19"}, "commit"=>"send"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Chatroom Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms" WHERE "chatrooms"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "chatroom_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", " asfdsfsd"], ["user_id", 14], ["created_at", "2017-11-19 19:35:09.198584"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-19 19:35:09.198584"], ["chatroom_id", 19]]
   (21.7ms)  COMMIT
  Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."chatroom_id" = $1 ORDER BY "messages"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["chatroom_id", 19], ["LIMIT", 2]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to messages: {:message=>" asfdsfsd", :user=>"federico", :chatroom_id=>19, :lastuser=>"federico"}
MessagesChannel transmitting {"message"=>" asfdsfsd", "user"=>"federico", "chatroom_id"=>19, "lastuser"=>"federico"}
```

The difference is that you are missing this line, which trigger your `received` function in `app/assets/javascripts/channels/division.coffee`

```
MessagesChannel transmitting {"message"=>" asfdsfsd", "user"=>"federico", "chatroom_id"=>19, "lastuser"=>"federico"}
```

This is the rest of my log

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-19 20:28:27 +0100
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-19 20:28:28 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
MessagesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
MessagesChannel is streaming from messages
```

The main things are

1. The first thing my server does at start up is a get request `GET '/cable' for 127.0.0.1` to the cable server, it is connecting to the websocket. This is what I include in my `routes.rb`

   ```
   mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
   ```

   I also get the following message

   ```
   Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
   ```
2. Then I get information that

   ```
   MessagesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
   ```

   and most important

   ```
   MessagesChannel is streaming from messages`
   ```

   It is `streaming from messages` because that is how I set my `Channel`, for you it should be:

   ```
   DivisionChannel is streaming from divisions_channel
   ```

   If the user leaves then `MessagesChannel stopped streaming from messages`

Also you can go in your `Developer Toolbar` Network Tab and select the cable entry. From the screenshot you can see that I selected the `Cable` and on the right I checked the `Frames` tab and I could find the following command sent from the server

```
{"command":"subscribe", "identifier":"{\"channel\":\"MessagesChannel\"}"}
```

Then when I receive the message from the server I have in my frames:

```
{"identifier":"{\"channel\":\"MessagesChannel\"}","message":{"message":"this is my test","user":"ezio","chatroom_id":19,"lastuser":"federico"}}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that form and index (or show for what matters) are on different pages. So I create a division on new view, but then I got redirected to index. Which makes no sense for actioncable usage. My intention was to start from a basic app with index, show, new views and make it real time. But I ignored a basic step which is having the form on the same view showing new records, in this case index. So after fixing that I'm back to the same problem I have in the other question. Which is creating record with a form (post) displaying them real time with actioncable.